# How to consecutively order and re-order array of numbers allowing for duplicate values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

Got a weird problem to solve that is tying my brain in knots trying to visualize. I have an array objects to maintain  that look something like this:

```
let approvers = [{order:1, dueDate: someDate},{order:2, dueDate: someDate}, 
                 {order:3, dueDate: someDate},{order:4, dueDate: someDate}];
```

Through the UI  the user can decide to adjust the order for an approver to be the same as another to allow tasks to run in parallel which would leave the collection looking like this

```
let approvers = [{order:1, dueDate: someDate},{order:1, dueDate: someDate}, 
                 {order:3, dueDate: someDate},{order:4, dueDate: someDate}];
```

When that happens I need a function to update the collection to set the order values to be consecutive  but allow for duplicates so it ends up looking like this

```
let approvers = [{order:1, dueDate: someDate},{order:1, dueDate: someDate}, 
                 {order:2, dueDate: someDate},{order:3, dueDate: someDate}];
```

Another possibility is that the end user can remove an approver from the collection leaving it looking like this

```
let approvers = [{order:1, dueDate: someDate},{order:2, dueDate: someDate}, 
                 {order:4, dueDate: someDate}];
```

And when that happens I need the function to update the collection to look like this

```
let approvers = [{order:1, dueDate: someDate},{order:2, dueDate: someDate}, 
                 {order:3, dueDate: someDate}];
```

Im using moment for date manipulation and lodash for basic sorting

in the below code mo = moment  lo = lodash

```
 private reorderApprovers(apps: IApprover[]): IApprover[] {
    let tempApps: IApprover[] = lo.orderBy(apps, ['order'], ['asc']);
    let previousOrder: number = 1;
    tempApps.forEach((app, index) => {
      if (index != 0) {
        if (app.order != previousOrder && app.order != previousOrder + 1) {
          app.order = previousOrder + 1;
          previousOrder++;
        }
      }
      else {
        app.order = previousOrder;
        previousOrder++;
      }
    });     
    return tempApps;
  }
```

Comment: One question, the due date + value always follows the order. As it can be inferred by the order, why store it? I mean you can compute it easily when needed.i.e store an overall due date on the item.

Comment: true and in reality it is computed  as such at the component level. I included it to show the important parts of the array of objects that I need to track but I can see that could confuse what my question is really about  and that is how to handle the ordering. ill update the example

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want with this assignment:

```
tempApps = [...apps]
    .sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order)
    .forEach((a, i) => a.order = !i ? 1 
                       : apps[i-1].order + (a.order > apps[i-1].order));
```

This first creates a shallow copy (in order not to mutate the original array); then that copy is sorted by `order`; and finally the `order` values are corrected with the logic that the first one should have `order` 1, and any next one should an `order` equal to the previous `order` or one more.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @trincot for getting my head moving in the right direction here's the solution that worked for me

```
  private reorderApprovers(apps: IApprover[]): IApprover[] {
    let tempApps: IApprover[] = lo.orderBy(apps, ['order'], ['asc']);
    let nextOrder: number = 1;
    let previousOrder: number = 1;
    tempApps.forEach((app, index) => {
      if (index != 0) {
        if (app.order != previousOrder && app.order != nextOrder) {
          previousOrder = nextOrder;
          nextOrder++;
          app.order = nextOrder;
        }
      }
      else {
        app.order = nextOrder;
        nextOrder++;
      }
    });     
    return tempApps;
  }
```